# Why modal popup shows black screen when its in DropdownList

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here i'm using Bootstrap with angular when i try to popup my modal with DropdowList its Shows black screen but when i use button its working Good please find where i'm doing mistake

```
<div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="Job(emp)">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="button" ng-click="Job(emp)" value="Job" />
```

**Angular.js**

```
 $scope.Job = function (emp) {
        $scope.Emp_Id = emp.Emp_Id

        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }
```

When its under Button its working Good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item" ng-click="Job()">Edit</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a></li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
$scope.Job = function () {
        //$scope.Emp_Id = emp.Emp_Id

        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/8Lozvmx8/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `modalclass{z-index:9999}` It may fix this problem